# How do I find out the element that initiated an event in sammyjs?

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

suppose I have the following markup

```
<ul class="app-nav">
  <li><a href="#!/testing">Link to testing route</a>
</ul>
...
<a href="#!/testing">Other link to testing route</a>
```

Using jQuery

```
$('a').click(function() {
   console.log( $(this) ); //the event sender and can be 'a' or 'ul>li>a'
});
```

With sammy.js

```
this.get('#!/testing', function(context) {
  //how I can get the event sender?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery bind your request to the document and check the target property:

```
$(document).on('click', function( e ){

    var sender = e.target; // <-- Your event initiator

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, [Event Context](http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/#Sammy.EventContext) seems to be what you're looking for.

> ***this.target***
>
> a DOM element that the event that holds this context originates from. For post, put and del routes, this is the form element that triggered the route.

So for a post request, you can get the serialised object from the submitted form.

```
this.post('#:id', function() {
  // this.target is the DOM form element that triggered the route
  console.log($(this.target).serialize());
});
```